# (Co)Registration in the preprocessing pipeline

Tags: fmri

I have a general question about registration and coregistration in the preprocessing pipeline of fMRI images. For me it is not clear what this is.

So, motion correction, slice time correction, spatial filtering, intensity normalization and temporal filtering are applied for each subject independently (i.e. for each session) and coregistration is applied between subjects. Is this correct?

What is the difference between registration and coregistration and normalization?